# Nest.js TypeORM FindOneBy returns null even with data on the database

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

So I have this entity...

```
import { Column, Entity, PrimaryColumn } from "typeorm";

@Entity('Users')
export class User {
  @PrimaryColumn({ type: 'nvarchar', length: 36, unique: true })
  UserId: string;

  @Column({ type: 'nvarchar', length: 100, unique: true })
  Email: string;

  @Column({ type: 'nvarchar', length: 36 })
  CrmUserId: string;

  @Column({ type: 'nvarchar', length: 36, nullable: true })
  AzureB2CUserId: string;

  @Column({ type: 'bit', default: false })
  IsActive: boolean;

  @Column({ type: 'nvarchar', length: 100 })
  CreatedBy: string;

  @Column({ type: 'datetime' })
  CreatedDate: Date;

  @Column({ type: 'nvarchar', length: 100, nullable: true })
  UpdatedBy: string;

  @Column({ type: 'datetime', nullable: true })
  UpdatedDate: Date;
}
```

and using TypeORM I want to get one record by the email, not the UserId. So I had this on the repository.

```
public async getUserByEmail(email: string): Promise<User | null> {
  let _res = await this._userRepository.findOne({ where: { Email: email, IsActive: true }})
  return _res;
}
```

But it always returns a null, even if the record exists, I was thinking of doing it with a CreateQueryBuilder, like this...

```
public async getUserByEmail(email: string): Promise<User | null> {
    let _res = await this._userRepository.createQueryBuilder()
        .select()
        .from(User, "Users")
        .where('email = :emailParameter', { email })
        .getOne();
    return _res;
}
```

But the result is the same, I keep getting null, I have no idea what I am doing wrong, because it works if I use the primary key on the findOne and findOneBy. Any help out there with this?

Comment: drop the `.select()` and the `.from()` from your `createQueryBuilder()`

Comment: @micaelLevi that made it work, thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. If you are using MongoDB then use `import { MongoRepository, Repository } from 'typeorm';` for the `_userRepository` type.
2. While using _userRepository findOneBy wrap the userId parameter in `import { ObjectId } from 'mongodb' const query  = {"_id":ObjectId(req.params.productId)}`
3. [OR have a look at this example](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/2530)

Answer (score 1):

know this due to the fact that where in the "entity" you give the default value in the "delete_date" to the user, you must definitely give `null`.

I wrote in my entity like this

```
   @DeleteDateColumn({
     name: 'deleted_date',
     type: 'timestamp',
     default: null, // default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)',
   })
   public deletedAt: Date;

   @CreateDateColumn({
     name: 'created_date',
     type: 'timestamp',
     default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)',
   })
   public createdAt: Date;

   @UpdateDateColumn({
     name: 'updated_date',
     type: 'timestamp',
     default: null
     onUpdate: 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)',
   })
   public updatedAt: Date;
```

you can't give values to a "delete_date" when you create a user